# Vim plugin to tidy HTML, that can be installed through Vundle?

Tags: vim, tidy

I have an HTML file that doesn't have any line breaks. Practically a huge portion of it is in a single line. I was trying to tidy that in Vim; I tried `gg=G`, which just tried to intend the first four lines that were on separate lines.

I tried that after the following commands:

```
:filetype indent on
:set filetype=html
:set smartindent
```

note:

- I tried in Sublime and it beautifully did it.
- I tested with this: http://pastebin.com/TgXnq2ef

Comment: Have you checked to see if the problem is actually that the line breaks in the file are different from what your OS expects?

Comment: Mmm, didn't check but since I copied the HTML from Safari in Mac and is working on MacVim in terminal in Mac, I assumed it shouldn't be related to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do it without plugin :)

Test this

```
:s/<[^>]*>/\r&\r/g
```

to split lines then remove spaces with

```
:g/^$/d
```

finally

```
gg=G
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: Cool, it did work! But somehow quite surprised as why Vim skipped a beat to get this relatively simple task for Sublime. That makes me think, we are missing something, nonetheless I am approving your answer :)

Comment: Btw, its `:%s/<[^>]*>/\r&\r/g`, you had made a small typo.

Comment: @JikkuJose You should report this bug to the tracker, maybe it will be included in the next roadmap :)

Answer (score 0):

For reformatting and clean up of HTML, I usually pipe this through [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net) or [html-beautify.js](http://jsbeautifier.org/):

```
:%! tidy --indent yes --wrap 0 --tidy-mark no --force-output true -quiet --show-errors 0 --show-warnings 0
:%! html-beautify.js --file -
```